# I can't root my components in an Angular project with Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

I'm using Angular 16.0.0 and Ionic 7.0.0
**Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'**

I try navigate to my 'home' component, I'm using:

`this.router.navigate(['/home']);`

But it isn't works.

I have this on my path:

`{ path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule) },`

[image: This is the problem]

I tried other solutions for the stackoverflow problem NG04002, but nothing worked, I read something about  but I don't know anything about it, I hope someone has a similar problem and can help me.

Comment: Share the routing TabsPageModule uses. I.e. is there an empty path route?

Comment: Apparently if it was an error with the route, it was calling "./tabs/tabs.module", when in fact it should have called ./tab1/tab1.module, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly routed in tabs routing module? If possible share tabs routing module.

Comment: It was wrong in the route that I wanted to reach, I corrected this and it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: This should be a comment.